# Maximum and Minimum using awk

Tags: unix, awk, max, min

How would you find the maximum and minimum a,b,c values for the rows that start with MATH from the following file?

```
TITLE     a       b       c
MATH      12.3    -0.42   5.5
ENGLISH   70.45   3.21    6.63
MATH      3.32    2.43    9.42
MATH      3.91    -1.56   7.22
ENGLISH   89.21   4.66    5.32
```

It can not be just 1 command line. It has to be a script file using BEGIN function and END.

I get the wrong minimum value and I end up getting a string for max when I run my program. Please help!

Here is my code for the column a:

```
BEGIN { x=1 }
{
 if ($1 == "MATH") {
        min=max=$2;
        for ( i=0; i<=NF; i++) {
                min = (min < $i ? min : $i)
                max = (max > $i ? max : $i)
        }
 }

}

END { print "max a value is ", max, " min a value is ", min }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code. It's hard to say what you did wrong without it.

Comment: Ok I have added my code.

Comment: You don't run it in a loop for all matches. Please see my example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code could demonstrate a concept of what you want:

```
awk '$1!="MATH"{next}1;!i++{min=$2;max=$2;}{for(j=2;j<=NF;++j){min=(min<$j)?min:$j;max=(max>$j)?max:$j}}END{printf "Max value is %.2f. Min value is %.2f.\n", max, min}' file
```

Output:

```
MATH      12.3    -0.42   5.5
MATH      3.32    2.43    9.42
MATH      3.91    -1.56   7.22
Max value is 12.30. Min value is -1.56.
```

Remove `1` to suppress the messages:

```
awk '$1!="MATH"{next};...
```

Script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

$1 != "MATH" {
    # Move to next record if not about "MATH".
    next
}
!i++ {
    # Only does this on first match.
    min = $2; max = $2
}
{
    for (j = 2; j <= NF; ++j) {
        min = (min < $j) ? min : $j
        max = (max > $j) ? max : $j
    }
}
END {
    printf "Max value is %.2f. Min value is %.2f.\n", max, min
}
```

Comment: For me its more easy to read `$1!="MATH"` compare to `!($1=="MATH")`

Comment: Aprreciate the reply this was the answer I needed. However why I you using j = 2 in the for loop and not j = 0?

Comment: `j` is a pointer to the target field number and the numbers starts at field number 2 (`$2`) whereas the reference strings (MATH, etc.) are at field 1 (`$1`).

Answer (score 1):

look at your for loop

it starts from i=0 so the condition should be

```
i<NF
```

instead of

```
i<= NF
```

try the following line instead of that line .... i hope you get what u are looking for

```
for(i=0;i<NF;i++){
```

rest all looks fine to me.... thanks

Answer (score 1):

The i variable in the for loop should at least begin with 2(the 2rd field), not 0, which represent the whole line, and end with NF.

```
BEGIN { x=1;min=2147483647;max=-2147483648}
{
 if ($1 == "MATH") {            
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
                min = (min < $i ? min : $i)
                max = (max > $i ? max : $i)
        }
 }

}

END { print "max a value is ", max, " min a value is ", min }
```

Run with command:(`testawk.script` for the above awk script filename, `test.data` for input data filename)

> cat test.data | awk -f testawk.script

output:

> max a value is  12.30  min a value is  -1.56

Comment: This works as well, however can you go into more depth on the reason of why i = 2?

Comment: @user2763235 Because the number field is started with field a, which is the second field. It this clear?

Answer (score -2):

I don't have a terminal handy on me right now but something along these lines will get the smallest of each line.

```
cat YOURFILE | grep "^MATH" | cat test | \   
while read CMD; do
    A=`echo $CMD |  awk '{ print $2 }'`
    B=`echo $CMD |  awk '{ print $3 }'`
    C=`echo $CMD |  awk '{ print $4 }'`

   #IF Statement for comparing the three of them 
   #echo the smallest
done
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I'm also realizing you probaby meant using only awk. My bad @luluyon